# java embedded OS X Applications VS System installed Java

Tags: java, macos, java-7, java-6

If a Mac OS X computer have instaled Java ( 6 - 7 - Both ??? ) & an Application (from AppStore) has Java ( 6 - 7 Which ??? ) embedded, Will the system used the Systemwide installed or the embedded Java ?

Why i ask, say i have 10 apps with embedded Java running at the same time & i have system installed Java, will Java be running once or 11 times ?

So if you have to use many Java Applications, should you build/install them with embedded Java or should you install Java on your system ?

If some Applications expect/need Java 6 & other Java 7, can you install both (see below) ?

- Mac OS X used to come with multiple Java versions installed, all provided by Apple, and an Application to control which Java version was used when or by what App. However that Application is removed by Apple from Java 6 & both Java's 6 -7 are from different providers now (Apple & Oracle) & have enough different approaches from each other to make me wonder if they can still coexist -

Comment: WHich Java apps have Java embedded

Comment: @Mark I think he meant if he should use system-preinstalled Java or custom installed Java. However, consider moving this question to superuser. (or ask different)

Comment: I general the question needs to be edited as not really that clear what is being asked - I think I see some question here which is why I answered but needs to be cleaned up to make sure that is the question

Answer (score 2):

Java always has run once per application. So in your process list there will be at least one Java process for each application.

You can install both Java 6 and Java 7 (and depending on OS earlier versions although I do not know where they come from) and also Java 8 development versions. See

Java 7 comes from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1880261.html) and 6 from [Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

The Application in its Info.plist tells which Java to use.